# Javascript is not getting executed when DOM/HTML is loaded browser cache

Tags: javascript, performance, browser-cache, etag

I am caching the dynamic content using the ETAG. There is javascript in  tag which in turn located at the end of body tag. This script tag make changes in DOM elements. But when DOM/HTML is loaded from browser cache, javascript is not getting executed.

Any work around to make this work?

Also I am observing caching is working fine with Chrome and mozilla, but not with OPERA. Is there any specific reason/bug in opera, which is causing this issue?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Got an issue. I am populating the js variables from php. So values of js variables are also cached.
e.g. 
<script>
var userList = <?php echo $csvUserList; ?>;
</scirpt>

So javascript script tag is getting executed every time. But values of the variables are same. I am caching dynamic pages with ETAG. Now I have included above php variable in a list to create ETAG. But still old values are getting used.